# How to take advantage of Cassandra partitioner using DataFrames?

Tags: scala, apache-spark, cassandra, apache-spark-sql, spark-cassandra-connector

According to [documentation](https://github.com/datastax/spark-cassandra-connector/blob/master/doc/16_partitioning.md), Cassandra Partitioner can help to reduce shuffles improving overall performance. To take advantage of partitioner I should use `keyBy` method. Given table:

```
CREATE TABLE data_storage.dummy (
id text,
value bigint,
PRIMARY KEY (id)
)
```

I can query a table using RDD API and DataFrame API

```
  val keySpace = "data_storage"
  val table = "dummy"

  //option 1
  private val df: DataFrame = session.read.format("org.apache.spark.sql.cassandra")
    .option("keyspace", keySpace)
    .option("table", table)
    .load
  println(df.rdd.partitioner) //prints None

  //option 2
  val rdd = session.sparkContext.cassandraTable(keySpace, table).keyBy("id")
  println(rdd.partitioner) //prints Some(CassandraPartitioner)
```

Is there any way to pass information to DataFrame reader about how data should be queried (something like `keyBy()` method for DataFrame)

Comment: Were you able to resolve this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You don't need to specify partitioner in case of DataFrame. You just need to make sure `pushdown` is set to `true` for the Cassandra DataFrame.
Check this doc [Automatic Predicate Pushdown and Column Pruning](https://github.com/datastax/spark-cassandra-connector/blob/master/doc/14_data_frames.md#automatic--predicate-pushdown-and-column-pruning).

Comment: pushdown is enabled by default right ? is there a need to enable it explicitly. It not very clear to me why   println(df.rdd.partitioner) //prints None ? shouldnt it be partitioned on something